# SQL query optimization - really nothing more to improve?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, sqlperformance

I have the following query. I picked it from mysql slow queries log:

```
SELECT AVG(item.duration) AS dur 
FROM `item` 
INNER JOIN item_step ON item_step.item_id = item.id 
WHERE
item_step.number = '2' AND 
(IS_OK(item_step.result) OR item_step.result2 IN ("R1", "R2")) AND 
item.time >= '2015-03-01 07:00:00' AND 
item.time < '2015-05-01 07:00:00';
```

As usually I tried to inspect it using explain:

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys              | key     | key_len | ref              | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item      | ALL  | PRIMARY,time               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL             | 790464 |    38.74 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | item_step | ref  | number,item_id,result2_idx | item_id | 4       | debug_db.item.id |      1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+----------------------------+---------+---------+------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Adding index to table `item` on `id` and `time` gave nothing.
Actually `time` column has an index,tables are connected using foreign keys and have an indexes..

I have no idea about what to do here. Is it really impossible to optimize this query to avoid using join_type  = ALL ?

Comment: Do you have index on item(number)? I would try add index on item(number, time,Id,duration).

Comment: @Tim3880 number belongs to item_step and yes it has an index. I will now try out index on item(time, id, duration)...

Comment: My bad and please ignore it.

Comment: @Tim3880 addiing this index helps to avoid using join type ALL. You could post your suggestion as an answer

Comment: Already feel better as long as someone try my ideas.

Comment: @BogdanBurim there is a possibility to make it even faster with the use of [covering index](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/) - in your case probably (number, item_id, result, result2) on item_step and (id, time, duration) on item - that allows the query to not read from table at all as all needed data are already stored in some index in sorted order. But it comes with price in terms of size of data and performance on insert/update, so should be only used when adding index on (number) is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already seem to have a FK from `item_step.item_id` to `item.item_id`, the only option you have for improvement is focusing on the parts being used to filter out records.

Slightly reformatting your query we have :

```
SELECT AVG(item.duration) AS dur 
  FROM `item` 
  INNER JOIN item_step 
     ON item_step.item_id = item.id 
    AND item_step.number = '2' 
    AND (IS_OK(item_step.result) OR item_step.result2 IN ("R1", "R2"))
  WHERE item.time >= '2015-03-01 07:00:00'
    AND item.time < '2015-05-01 07:00:00';
```

- First thing to notice is `IS_OK(item_step.result)`. I have no clue what's behind this function but I'm pretty sure it blocks the optimizer from using any index this field efficiently. If the formula is something that can be written in the query directly I would suggest to do so. (e.g. `IN (1, 4, 9)`, or `IN (SELECT OK FROM result_values)` etc...)
- Going by the field-names I'm going to assume that we FIRST want to reduce the `item_id` list to a minimum first and then use that reduced list to work on the `item_step` table. To do so you'll need an index on the `time` field first. I'm assuming that the `item_id` field is automatically included in the index as it's the PK field, but I'm no MySQL specialist and it might also depend on your storage engine. Anyay, in MSSQL that's how it would work, YMMV.
- The second thing to do then is to go with this list of `item_id`s to the `item_step` table and reduce the number of records there. For this you'll want a compound index on `item_id, number, result2, result`. If you manage to write the IS_OK() function 'inline' into the query you might want to try swapping the last two fields around... something you'll need to test.

From what I read here and there, MySQL does not support something like `INCLUDE` on indexes in the same way as MSSQL does. A way around that would be to create a 'covering' index on `time, duration` on `item`. That way, everything can be done from the index directly, at the cost of more disk-space and CPU requirements when adding data to the `item` table.

In short:

- add index on `item` on `time, duration`
- add index on `item_step` on `item_id, number, result2, result`
- see if you can *inline* the IS_OK() function.

Comment: As can be seen from explain in the question, index on time was checked and still not used - so that condition is very probably not selective enough. Your (time, duration) is in InnoDB equivalent to (time, duration, id) (if id is primary key), so it "forbids" changing order of the join, bacause it cannot be used to get the right item for actual item_step. But as it seems most conditions are on item_step so (from what we can see from question without tables statistics) the "reversed" join order seems better to me.

Comment: Inlining IS_OK made 2.2x positive changes, the other things were already done(indexes), some did not change situation at all (reformatting where conditions to join rules). Thanks!

Comment: Reformatting wasn't really supposed to give much benefit. I guess most (modern) RDBMS's don't really care about the order of the predicates, but it makes it easier for us humans to understand what's going on by grouping things to their logical location. Too bad about the time field not being selective enough. Hopefully the current situation is 'fast enough'. Good luck!

Comment: @user1786423: I couldn't get a clear answer from google, so thanks for confirming how it works!

Comment: @deroby yep, it depends on engine, but InnoDB uses cluetering by primary key (always, you cannot cluster by other index), so primary key i always appended to each index. In case of no primary, first unique is used, or internal "autoincrement-like" clustering key is generated if nothig is unique.

Comment: @user1786423 - if that `time` range is more than (about) 20% of the table, the index on `time` will not be used.

Comment: @RickJames thats what I meant with "index on time was checked and still not used - so that condition is very probably not selective enough"